# last command showing dns server instead of ip address

Tags: centos, firewalld

Logging in to the server recently, I saw this message:

```
Last login: Mon Jul 17 01:14:15 2017 from dns2.redstation.co.uk
```

last command also lists the the same address a few times.

As far as I know it should log the ip address, I don't know enough about Linux though.
Is this something that I should worry about? 
And how do I restrict access from that address in the future?

I got its ip address by simply pinging it, and added that ip to reject list of firewalld using this command:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='80.84.49.136' reject"
```

I'm not sure if this would work or not.

CentOs7 with firewalld is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a dedicated server from RedStation and you're not expecting a login from their systems it would be worth pinging their support team a ticket asking for an explanation of the login. (Just first make sure that you haven't enabled `ssh` service monitoring and forgotten about it. Otherwise you'll look pretty silly.)

The process that displays the `Last login` line attempts to reverse lookup the recorded IP address 80.84.49.136 to give you a "friendly" name from DNS. Personally I'd say that most times "dns2.redstation.co.uk" is easier to understand than "80.84.49.136". YMMV.

The `last` command records all logins (and most logouts), and there are various options to display remote hosts by name and/or IP address. If your username is `ali` you could try `last ali` to see more detail of what's going on. Use `man last` to find out the various options for the command.

Once you have identified the reason for the unexpected login you can decide the appropriate course of action. If your password has been compromised then there's little point just blocking the offending source IP address.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a VPS, I contacted the website we bought it from, but they had no idea what was going on. I also changed the password last night but I got another login this morning again.

Comment: Also our data center is Hetzner.